# Alternative To Inner Loop Queue Publishing

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I want to publish data in queue in asynchronous way using camelContext blueprint.

**Complete Context:**

```xml
<camelContext id="xContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="notifPublisher">
        <from id="notifService" uri="cxfrs:bean:xRequestService"/>
        <inOnly id="toRequestQueue" uri="activemq:queue:{{data.queue}}?jmsMessageType=Text"/>
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" id="setContentType"/>
    </route>
    <route id="xReceiver">
        <from id="dataqueue" uri="activemq:queue:{{data.queue}}?jmsMessageType=Text"/>
        <log id="logDataQueue_" message="Data/DatAs ${body}"/>
        <bean id="fetchUsers" method="fetchUsers" ref="dataProcessor"/>
        <bean id="checkDataInList" method="checkDataInList" ref="dataProcessor"/>
        <loop doWhile="true" id="_loop1">
            <simple>${header.mailMap} != 'EMPTY'</simple>
            <bean id="sendInQueuePerData" method="sendInQueuePerData" ref="dataProcessor"/>
            <to id="emailqueue" uri="activemq:queue:{{email.queue}}?jmsMessageType=Text"/>
        </loop>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

emailQueue is begin handing by other emailProcessor.
emailProcessor is sending emails to SMTP.

Problem is DataProcessor is blocked until it will complete all input data.
Its should not be blocked once it sends data to queue.

Comment: Can you share the complete code you are running ?

Comment: Hi Aditya, Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a for-loop here. Pass the output of checkDataInList into a splitter and then to the Email processor.

This will be non-blocking and is the more Camel way of doing things.